# Can You Get Contact Phone Number Labels

Tags: maui

I'm getting phone numbers for contacts in my MAUI app.  However, it would be significantly more useful if I could get the label associated with a number, like "Home", "Work", "Mobile", etc.  I looked all over and can't find it in there; is there some way to get that in .NET MAUI?

Comment: For clarity, please provide a link to the doc you are using to know how to do what you did so far, plus a brief snippet of code showing how you access the phone numbers. Thanks. [I am not knowledgeable on this topic, so won't be able to help.]

Comment: with the MAUI Contacts API, it appears that they don't expose this.  You would probably need to write platform specific code to do this

Comment: Got it, thanks Jason.  I thought that was the case but just wanted to do a sanity check.